# Is there any formula for OpenCalc which can count rows that contain some values but do not contain other values?

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have the following cell structure in `OpenCalc`:

```
      |--A--|--B--|--C--|--D--|--E--|
|--1--|  A1 |  B1 |  C1 |  D1 |  E1 |
|--2--|  A1 |  B1 |  C1 |  D1 |  E1 |
|--3--|  A1 |  C1 |  D1 |  E1 |  F1 |
```

Is there any way to create a formula, which can count all the rows from this data structure, that has `A1` in it, but does not have `B1` in it?

Data in the cells can go from `A1 --> O1`, every row will have 5 columns of data, and data in a single row can not be repeated.

With the above excerpt, the cell after calculating the formula, should contain 1 for me.

Comment: Yes, =count.if(...)

Comment: @LPChip, this one is actually more complicated than that.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 I guess I don't understand the question then. If you want to count all the occurrences of a text in a range, count.if is the function to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more complicated than it looks.  One problem is that the target values can be in any column.  Another is that one target must be in no column.  Another is that you can't deal with the entire range, the rules need to be applied row-by-row.  With more coffee, a one-step formula might dawn on me, but what came to mind is a solution using a helper column.

I'll use column F for the helper.  There are lots of variants that will give you the correct value, but use this in F1, and then copy down the column as needed:

```
=(COUNTIF(A1:E1,"A1")*(COUNTIF(A1:E1,"B1")=0))
```

The first COUNTIF returns a `TRUE` or `1` if "A1" is found in any column (you specify that values can appear only once in a row).  The second COUNTIF looks for "B1" in every column and returns `TRUE` or `1` only if no column contains it.  Multiplying those results together produces a `1` for the row if both conditions are true and `0` otherwise.

Summing the values in column F gives you your count.  You can stick a sum at the bottom of the column, or use `=SUM(F:F)` in a convenient location.

I use LO Calc, and it has a setting to use standard Excel notation rather than the OpenOffice standard.  In OpenOffice, you may need to look for a similar setting or tweak the formulas to reflect how OpenOffice is set to specify cell and range references.

Comment: I will accept this as the correct answer, because I think this is as close as you can get without using macros in OpenCalc:) In the meanwhile, I've managed to resolve the issue, with a simmilar, altough rather complicated work around, using a LARGE helper table:)